# Is there a way I can make r work within a list

Tags: r

Is there anyway to make r work 'within' a list?  I.e. to make it assume a certain list is the current environment?

I have some code in which all the objects that I manipulate are in a list, call it "mylist".

Is there a way I can tell r that all objects are to be looked for in mylist, so that instead of writing

```
mylist$object
```

I can just write

```
object
```

and r will automatically look for it in mylist?

I am a fairly new r user so apologies if I've misused any terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `with()`?

For example,

```
mylist <- list(object = c(1:10),
               obj2 = c("a", "b"))

with(mylist, sum(object))
[1] 55

with(mylist, obj2)
[1] "a" "b"

# etc
```

If not, it sounds like you might not actually want to store you objects as elements in a list; instead, it might be better to create individual objects in your global environment to reference.

If you have multiple lists, each containing the same kind of objects, and you want to perform the same sort of tasks on those lists, then it would be time to look into writing a function. Still, even with a function you will want to pull those components apart (or pass the function to `with()`!) to be able to call those elements of a list by their names (e.g. `object` or `obj2`).

It might help to read up on lists and environments in R. A few good resources to that end:

(lists) - http://rforpublichealth.blogspot.com/2015/03/basics-of-lists.html

(environments) - http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Comment: This looks like it's in the right area, but what if I have dozens of tasks I want to do?  wouldn't this result in alot more typing?

Comment: @fair21comic Just updated my answer in response to your comment. Take a look and see if it helps; if not, it might be best to update your questions with more details on what you intend to do and perhaps a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)